# Vue.js 3 router weird issue

Tags: vue.js, router

I have this weird issue and here are the important things to bear in mind:

- it's working perfectly fine locally
- it worked perfectly fine for months (locally and prod)
- I did not touch anything, only pushed completely unrelated changes
- I reverted it back to a previous state, the issue persists
- I rebooted the VPS, restarted PM2 etc

The error(s):

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__vccOpts')

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'displayName' in undefined

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

I get those 3 errors,"split" when I click on the route, the others if I try again.
Everything happens in vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3295 apparently

Here's an odd behaviour that I noticed. Let's say that my app has A, B, C and D routes/components.
I start the app (I'm therefore on component A), it won't let me access B, the other routes are fine.

I go to C, refresh, I get the bug. But now I can go to B. Once in B, if I refresh, the issue "teleports itself" and now B has an issue again but I can access C.

At ANY point, I can access D, no problem. This route doesn't seem to be problematic. Even if I refresh.

Problematic routes seem to be the ones with params in them... However, I can't access route B (which has params) from the root of my site (which doesn't have any). So, there is an issue even when first starting the site.

I tried to use createHashHistoryMode instead, no luck, same behaviour.

I basically can access the whole site but I need to make the bug appear somewhere (by refreshing a problematic component) and then I can access the previously problematic route...

Any idea?

It will be hard to share the code, that's a massive project with a back end and because it's working locally, I can't really replicate the behaviour on demand and like I said, it used to work for months on end so, I'd just be sharing a working code anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: First, do you have any router hooks?

Second, how do you pass params, using `$router.push({...params:{})`?

A tip: try using hooks to observe where the error happens.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. No hooks, my implementation is rather bare bone.
this.$router.push({name: 'Messenger', params: {id: this.user._id, pm: "null"}})
this.$router.push(`/Messenger/${this.user._id}/null`)
both give me the same result. Both are in use throughout the site for months without issue. And both work locally.

Comment: I think the issue is somehow related to an async operation. Seemingly, it is a router-dependent issue. So, please follow the failure-detecting scenario. If the problem persists, let us know in more detail. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html

Comment: Working on it, still quite a beginner so it might take me a while. I just did some testing, it seems that the only routes that are problematic are the ones that have more than 1 param in the url... Quite interesting, I think...

Comment: OKay so, it's not a router issue. It seems that my back can send data but not receive any (or at least something like that). Users cannot send messages, buttons that fetch data do not work. So, I was chasing a consequence with one degree of separation :/

Comment: Some closure: My local package lock and the one on the VPS were out of sync. It wasn't a router issue after all.